# MySQL Value for the date of last edit in row

Tags: mysql

I have a DB with products
Example:

```
ID   Brand  Produkt Name    Price €  Date of last edit
1    XXX    XXXXX           100,00   2015-02-2015 10:20:46
```

Is there a way that my Date of last edit updates every time this ROW with ID 1 is changed or eddited in any way(or created)?

I defined the column as TIMESTAMP with the current date as default value, but that only shows me the creation date.

Comment: have a look at [on update current_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Taking a look right now, thank you!